# Specific normalization problem

Tags: normalization

Let's say I have a vector $v$ which will remain immutable and I want to normalize $w$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{N} v_i w_i = 1$

I don't know if there is an easy or efficient way to do it, but I can't think of any.

Edit: I will try to explain it more in detail with words.

$v$ is a distribution that has values between zero and one, and $w$ is another distribution that will be my weighting factor. This distribution $w$ will have values between 0 and 20, and I want to normalize this $w$ such that when I apply my weights to $v$ the total sum will be 1. Therefore, I cannot change the values of $v$, and I can change the values of $w$ to scale them in a way that $\sum_{i=0}^{N} v_i w_i = 1$

Thanks.

Comment: What is "$w$" originally and what operations do you wish to perform on it to "normalize" it?  If you're allowed to multiply all components by a common value, for instance, then the answer is to form the linear combination and, if it's nonzero, divide each component of $w$ by that value.  But that's so simple and obvious that I'm supposing you have some other situation in mind: what could it be?

Comment: Does setting $w:=v/\|v\|_2^2$ solve your problem?

Comment: whuber I'm confused by your solution, even if it's simple it could work because I don't have any constraint. I just need that the sum of its multiplication is 1.

Comment: Alex, that solution doesn't normalize $w$, it basically replaces all the values I have. The proportion should be kept, the same way when I want to normalize a vector to have values between 0 and 1: the content changed but the relation between the components remains. I want that proportion to be kept in $w$.

Comment: My solution indeed is simple and it will always work provided the sum of $v_iw_i$ is nonzero.  If it *is* zero, you cannot achieve your goal by rescaling.  I'm not asking about a "constraint": I'm just trying to see whether your question really has this simple solution or if there's something else going on.

Comment: I tried $z = w/(v*w)$, and then $\sum z v$ and it doesn't work, I got a 10. Maybe because of the range of values in w?

Comment: I have merely noted that given the original vectors $v$ and $w$ with $\sum_i v_i w_i = \lambda \ne 0$, then the vector $w/\lambda$ solves your problem because $$\sum_i v_i \left(\frac{w_i}{\lambda}\right) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_i v_i w_i = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda}=1.$$

Comment: Okay! Now I got it. Thank you very much whuber : )